# SSL with Jetty Built into Jar on EC2

Tags: servlets, ssl, amazon-ec2, jetty

Good Day,

I have been struggling to find documentation for "Setting up SSL With Jetty" but there is nothing. I basically have a Jetty Server set up in my Java Program as such. My Java program is compiled into a .jar file, and it can be run instantly on my AMAZON EC2 instance. All Jetty libraries are inside the .jar itself.

It works great on EC2. But I need these Jetty URL's to be secure and on SSL.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

private static Server server;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Servers!");

    server = new Server();
    Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
    connector.setPort(8081);
    server.addConnector(connector);

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet()),"/*");
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new PostServlet()),"/post/*");

    Thread monitor = new CommandThread();
    monitor.start();

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

}

Can I know what can be done to enable SSL on these links/servlets?

Comment: btw with my programs open it looks like this
user      5524  5492  1 08:28 pts/0    00:00:00 java -jar Server.jar
user      5574  5548  0 08:29 pts/1    00:00:00 grep java
user      5572  5548  0 08:29 pts/1    00:00:00 grep jetty

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to refer you to some code for this:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-server/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ssl/SSLSelectChannelConnectorLoadTest.java?h=jetty-8

You are mostly interested in the startServer() method as that is where the jetty server of the test case is being configured for ssl.  I linked you the jetty-8 version of the test since you are using SelectChannelConnector you are using either 7 or 8.  Jetty 9 has a bit different configuration of the server connectors.  We'll have to add in an embedded example for this ssl configuration and document that in our jetty 9 documentation sometime.  I'll link that here so folks can see it when we add that example.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html